# security when using MyModel.objects.get(name=some_var) in Django

Tags: django, validation

Is it safe to query with object.get without escaping or validation user submitted value?

For example:

```
some_var = request.POST.get('some_key')
obj = MyModel.objects.get(name=some_var)
```

Can the user submit malicious data?

Thanks

Comment: Could also use some_var = request.POST['some_key']

Comment: @dotty: you don't wanna retrieve elements from the POST dictionary this way, because if the key does not exist, an exception is raised. Always use get() when possible, as pablo did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Django ORM is supposed to take care of querying the underlying DB safely on your behalf.